# installing the PDO MySQL extension Driver on lampp server

Tags: mysql, lamp, extension

In Terminal Shows:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]           
pdo_mysql extension is not installed error show in my terminal during run time on lampp server with local server .Using this command it shows:
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>
```

I think driver not install.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option `--with-pdo-mysql` In your *php.ini*, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```